# javascript random content in tooltip. How to add space when needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, tooltip

I use Jquery to render a tooltip from hidden `<span>`. What i do is that i store each `<span>` value in javascript variables and then i append theses variable into my tooltip like this `AppendTo tooltip(var1+var2+var3+etc..)`

My problem is that i need to make a paragraph space (padding) between some of the content displayed. Sometimes my tooltip only displays var1 and var2 (var3 and var4 are empty).

For the spacing i'm actually using the css `padding-bottom` on var2. So if var3 is not empty the space is needed, but if var3 is empty i get an unwanted space..

I try to figure out how could i add a space only when i'm sure that after var2 there would be some content. I'm thinking of somekind of counter. Like

```
if var1 not empty counter++
if var2 not empty counter++
if var3 not empty counter++
If counter > 2 var2 = var2 + space
```

But maybe you guys have a better idea :)

Below my code :

```
<script>
first_name = '';
last_name = '';
phone = '';
email = '';
address = '';
tip_first_name = '';
tip_last_name = '';
tip_phone = '';
tip_email = '';
tip_address = '';

first_name = $(this).children('span[class=p_first_name]').attr("data-tooltip");
    if(first_name != null)tip_first_name = '<span class="tooltip_first_name">'+first_name+'</span>';
last_name = $(this).children('span[class=p_last_name]').attr("data-tooltip");
    if(last_name != null)tip_last_name = '<span class="tooltip_last_name">'+last_name+'</span>';
phone = $(this).children('span[class=p_phone]').attr("data-tooltip");
    if(phone != null)tip_phone = '<span class="tooltip_phone">'+phone+'</span>';
email = $(this).children('span[class=p_email]').attr("data-tooltip");
    if(email != null)tip_email = '<span class="tooltip_email">'+email+'</span>';
address = $(this).children('span[class=p_address]').attr("data-tooltip");
    if(address != null)tip_address = '<span class="tooltip_address">'+address+'</span>';

$('#hint').before('<div id="tip" class="tip"><div class="tip-personn">'+tip_first_name+tip_last_name+tip_phone+tip_email+tip_address+'</div></div>');

</script>
<style>
.tooltip_last_name{
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: To clarify; are you asking about how to add style/spacing to div.personn?

Comment: Yes but only if i have one the next variable (phone, email or address) not empty. In reality i have more than just 3 variables (got about 20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SebAshton/wLcVR/) should solve your issue, it uses an css adjacent sibling selector (seen below) so will target the 2nd, 3rd, 4th (and so on) span.

```
div.tip span + span {
     padding-top: 10px;
}
```

More information on sibling and child selectors [here](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Comment: Hey thx man! That's awesome! I think i used this long long time ago but i never thought an instant to use for this case. Thanks anyway!! Helps me a lot :)